# How to load a table with composite key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to load the below table using SQL. In my Ldirectory table I have the combination of `SY` and `LIDENTIFIER` as primary key and I'm trying to run this query

```
insert into S_User.LDIRECTORY (SY,LIDENTIFIER,ONAME,TELNUMBER) 
select  2013,D.CODE, D.NAME, D_YEAR.PHONE_NUMBER       
from    WHS.D   WHS.D_YEAR   
where   WHS.D.D_KEY=WHS.D_YEAR.D_KEY
```

and the error that I'm receiving is:

```
SQL Error ORA-00001 unique constraint violated

Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

How can I solve this issue? I think during the insertion its treating the SY column as primary key itself but I have just one same value for that column.

Comment: can you show your table create statement? You probably have a unique constraint defined on `SY` and/or `LIDENTIFIER' (or another column) individually. Either that, or your select is returning duplicate values for D.CODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should indicate the name of the unique constraint that was violated.  Assuming the constraint in question is the primary key rather than some other unique constraint defined on the table and assuming that the primary key constraint is a composite constraint defined on the combination of `SY` and `LIDENTIFIER` as you indicate, that implies that your query is returning duplicate rows.

The query you are running returns a hard-coded value of 2013 for `SY`.  So you would expect the constraint to be violated if there are any two rows in the result where `D.CODE` are the same.  Are you certain that you expect `D.CODE` to be unique across the entire result set?  It's hard to guess based on the names of the objects (no idea what `D` might represent, no idea why `D_YEAR` would have a `PHONE_NUMBER` column, etc) but I would tend to guess that one row in `D` might map to multiple rows in `D_YEAR` in which case there would be multiple rows in the result that had the same `D.CODE` value thus violating the constraint.

If you are convinced that the query should not return any two rows with the same `D.CODE` value, you could use DML error logging to write the rows that violate the constraint to an error table so that you could analyze the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin. There was actually one duplicate row which caused this error.